# JS Fiddle jQuery Click Event Not Firing

Tags: jquery

What is wrong with this jQuery (see JS Fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huufL/21/)). The click event won't fire. It must be something simple, but I just can't see it:

```
var form;
var submitting;
var submitBtn;

$(document).ready(function () {
    form = $("#form");
    submitting = $("#submitting");
    submitBtn = $("#submitBtn");

    // set the submitting div height to that of the form
    $(submitting).css("height", $(form).height());

    $(submitting).css("opacity", 0);

    //alert(submitBtn);

    // transition in when the button is clicked
    $(submitBtn).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        alert("why don't I fire!");

        $(form).animate({
            opacity: 0
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: its working now http://jsfiddle.net/huufL/23/, i;ve changed the o=postion:absolute to relative

Comment: you could also consider using `$(submitBtn).on('click', function(){})`

Comment: remove `top:0` from your `#submitting` and it will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine. Remove `top:0` from this element

```
#submitting {
    display:table;
    position:absolute;
    /*top:0;*/
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huufL/25)

This happend because `submitting` element overlap your `#form` element. This can be fixed also giving `submitting` a negative `z-index`:

```
#submitting {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

like this example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huufL/28/)

Comment: why is `top:0` causing a problem? I was trying to get the **sending your details** text inside the red box, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huufL/26/)

Comment: Because as i wrote `overlap your #form element`. It has height from this `$(submitting).css("height", $(form).height());`

Answer (score 2):

Actually user was not able to click on the button, since the div `submitting` is overlapping the form. Change the position of div to relative, then it will work fine

```
#submitting {
    display:table;
    position:relative;
    top:0
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/huufL/23/)